# Python object conversion

Tags: python

Assume that we have an object `k` of type `class A`. We defined a second `class B(A)`. What is the best practice to "convert" object `k` to `class B` and preserve all data in `k`?

Comment: In what way are you looking to convert from one to the other? Do you wish to keep all of the member variables of the class B object, but use the parent class A's set of methods?

Comment: Is this Pretty Poor Polymorphism?  Are A and B subclasses of a common superclass?  If so, this is the wrong thing to do?  Do you wish that A had the same methods as B?  This is done through multiple-inheritance.  Please explain why you think you need this because -- in Python -- you're doing it wrong if you think you need casting or type conversion.

Comment: Also really curious about your use case. Is this just for fun, or have you found this to be a better way of adressing some problem, other than with the help of classical polymorphism?

Comment: Depending on your problem, one of [these two methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/597243/952580) for achieving a similar result might be suitable, without feeling like a hack.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This does the "class conversion" but it is subject to collateral damage. Creating another object and replacing its `__dict__` as BrainCore posted would be safer - but this code does what you asked, with no new object being created.

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other


a = A()
a.value = 5

a.__class__ = B

print a + 10
```

Answer (score 8):

```
a = A() # parent class
b = B() # subclass
b.value = 3 # random setting of values

a.__dict__ = b.__dict__ # give object a b's values

# now proceed to use object a
```

Would this satisfy your use case? Note: Only the instance variables of b will be accessible from object a, not class B's class variables. Also, modifying variables in a will modify the variable in b, unless you do a deepcopy:

```
import copy
a.__dict__ = copy.deepcopy(b.__dict__)
```

Comment: Actually, no variables will be copied.  Since `a` and `b` now both share the same `__dict__`, setting `a.value` changes `b.value` too.

Comment: Actually on doing this, the "a" object should be destroyed immediately.  Else one does end up with two different objects, in different classes sharing the same attributes - there are few worse scenarios than this. (It is scary to play around even at the interactive prompt)

Answer (score 2):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, parent_instance, c):
        # initiate the parent class with all the arguments coming from
        # parent class __dict__
        super().__init__(*tuple(parent_instance.__dict__.values()))
        self.c = c

a_instance = A(1, 2)
b_instance = B(a_instance, 7)
print(b_instance.a + b_instance.b + b_instance.c)
>> 10
```

Or you could have a sperate function for this:

```
def class_converter(convert_to, parent_instance):
    return convert_to(*tuple(parent_instance.__dict__.values()))

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
            self.c = 5
```

But using the 2nd method, I wasn't able to figure out how to pass additional values