# How can I extend an object's class to a subclass?

Tags: python, instance

I have instance `a` of class `A`, and I want to make it also an instance of class `B` (which inherits from `A`).

I have tried this, but is is not behaving as expected:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

a = A()
isinstance(a, A)   # True
B.__init__(a)
isinstance(a, B)   # False, I wished it was True...
```

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464154/8837809) but I think my problem is a bit more general: here only the methods from `B` will apply to `a`, but I want `a` to be a full-fledged instance of `B`, *i.e.* also with member variables etc (as though `a` had been directly created as an instance of `B`, but with the inheritance from `A` in a state exactly similar to `a`).

How can I do this??
I don't mind creating a new instance if necessary, as I long as I can restore the exact same state in the end.

**EDIT:** I have also seen answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597199/8837809), but they either only create a new instance of `B` and retrieve one field from `a` (that will be hard to extend to complicated `A` classes with many attributes) or just set `a.__class__ = B`  which does not create attributes of `B`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597199/converting-an-object-into-a-subclass-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an object into a subclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597199/converting-an-object-into-a-subclass-in-python)

Comment: in your code B is a subclass of A. `B(A)`. you want it the other way around `A(B)`

Comment: You basically need to combine both your approach and the other answer: set the `__class__` *and* run some sort of `__init__` on the object. Note that this really sounds like a bad idea in the first place, there are probably better approaches 99% of the time.

Comment: @LiorCohen can you explain your thought? Is there a reason for what you say? To me `A` is a generic class, and `B`  is a subclass of `A` with additional functionalities. At some point I finally need these functionalities so I want to extend the class of `a` to `B`. Why should that be the other way round?

Comment: @deceze could you explain why you think it is a bad approach, and how could it be circumvented?

Comment: `B.__init__(a)` does not make a B type. it is just regular function. If you want "cast" make B __init__ accecpt another argument (`__init__(self, obj)` ) and assign obj attributes to self.