How can I convert one class into another which is child class?
I lack of experience in programming. I have the next issue. I have a two classes. Class File which is a parent class and PyFile which is an inheritance from File.
from anytree import NodeMixin
class File(NodeMixin):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        # also it has some other attribs from inheritance

class PyFile(File):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        super().__init__(var1, var2)
        instance_py_file_var = "some_value"

In a code I have list of File objects and by using function check_the_file I want to convert File object into PyFile object if it has the needed conditions.
# part of the code
files_lst = [File(element, var2) for element in files_lst]
py_files_lst = [check_the_file(file) for file in files_lst]

def check_the_file(file: File):
    if file.path.endswith(".py"):
         return PyFile(file)

So, I don't know how to implement this convertion from File into PyFile in my case. Should I use __call__ method in PyFile or just copying attributes or find easiest solution? Could you please help me with that issue?
I have looked at the answers on duplicated theme but the solutions were based on python 2.x versions, and can have more exclusive solution for python 3.x versionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/597199/converting-an-object-into-a-subclass-in-python

Use the accepted answer from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/597243/476. That's still perfectly cromulent advice for Python 3.
